# How to set AS2 as dialect in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2, dialect

I have to do a banner ad. I'm not used to work that way in flash, I just did a lot of as3 gaming stuff. The specification says, I should use as2, if possible. But in the AS-Settings I just can pick AS3 or ECMA as Dialect.

Can I just write AS2, or do I have to set the fla to as2? If I have to, how can I do it.

Comment: check the .fla document's publish settings. you should be able to change the actionscript version there

Comment: Thank you. I you write an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Comment: I see no reason why anyone should still use AS2, unless said project relies on some ancient AS2 dependency

Comment: I dont know. Thats what the specification of the newspaper says, where the banner is going to be placed.

Comment: Unless it's running in a separate environment (ie., such as ScaleForm), there's no reason they could dictate that.  If it's a newspaper, they're market is every-day end-users, and if they have Flash Player 9 or higher, it's going to support AS3.  As of 2009, market-share of clients older than v9 accounted for less than 0.3% (http://www.adobe.com/products/player_census/flashplayer/enterprise_penetration.html).  Write it in AS3.

Comment: Can it be because of the click-tag?

Answer (score 1):

I do a lot of Flash banners where I work. When the specs tell you that you need to use ActionScript 2, you're best of doing exactly that. Many publishers have tools that process banner ads, and reject them if they do not meet certain criteria. We use [Cadreon](http://cadreon.com.au/) most often which does exactly that.

A lot of the reason is that the platform will promise to get the largest reach with a client's media. That means they typically only accept *really* old formats (like Flash Player 8, AS2) to make sure they hit as many consumers as possible.

It might seem odd that they need SWFs this ancient - but consider that there are a lot of corporations that do not update software on their machines for many years at a time.